# How should I handle exception when opening disk cache?

Tags: android

In some Activities, I need resources, that may not be available on rare occasions. For instance, opening a disk cache may throw IOException. How should I handle this? Display a dialog, throw a RuntimeException, something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on what the app is doing.

Is the disk operation 100% necessary for that part of the operation? If yes, than sure, put a dialogue telling the user that the Storage is not accessible and the app can't work without it.

But if it's just a caching that will speed up future open of the app, don't bother the user for that. Just fail silently and let the app try again next time.